# If I make the tungsten filament on a light bulb thinner with more twists will it make more heat?

Tags: heat, light

If I make a incandescent light bulb with a sturdy and thicker filament will it also increase the temperature or just make it more durable?

Comment: There are multiple things that have to be balanced in a lightbulb. The filament temperature cannot be too high or the filament will fail, and/or the color temperature will be higher than desired. So you may be able to tweak the filament a bit, but you probably cannot change it a lot without messing up something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a tungsten bulb, the light output is related to both the surface area of the filament and its temperature. While the *heat* output is simply the input power minus the light power (which is usually in the range of 5% of the input power, can be 10% for halogens). Having a thicker filament will decrease the resistance which will cause more current to flow *at the same voltage* which results in more power and thus more heat, but a thicker filament *at a constant* power won't necessarily result in more heat, power out = power in.

Heat (watts) ~~= 0.95*input power (watts) for an incandescent globe.

Note: A tungsten heat globe will put out *marginally* more heat and marginally less light (I say marginally because even in the light globe, 95% of the power is heat anyway)

Answer (score 2):

A thicker filament (of the same material) will decrease resistance and therefore increase current flow, which in turn will increase power (P = IV) so yes, it'll make it hotter.

Comment: Just thinking... a thicker filament will also have more surface to radiate from, and this would tend to make it cooler (in the sense that the equilibrium temp for a given current would be lower). Also we are implicitly assuming here that the filament is powered by a voltage source and current will adapt to the filament's resistance.